# Unable to login to Quora using Selenium webdriver in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, quora

I am using a Selenium module in Python to log into Quora. It works fine for Facebook, but I am getting an error on the `send_keys('my_email')` line while trying it on Quora:

I am using the following script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.quora.com/')
time.sleep(60)

username = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
time.sleep(60)
username.send_keys('my_email')
time.sleep(60)

password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
time.sleep(60)
password.send_keys('my_password')
time.sleep(60)

password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close
```

Sleep time is not a problem here, because I tried executing a script line by line using the Python shell.

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       password.send_keys('my_password')   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 293, in send_keys
>       self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
>   line 370, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 173, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 164, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) ElementNotVisibleException: Message: u'Element is not currently
>   visible and so may not be interacted with' ; Stacktrace:
>       at fxdriver.preconditions.visible (file:///c:/users/siddhesh/appdata/local/temp/tmpgwft3s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:8791:5)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_ (file:///c:/users/siddhesh/appdata/local/temp/tmpgwft3s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11438:1)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///c:/users/siddhesh/appdata/local/temp/tmpgwft3s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11455:11)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///c:/users/siddhesh/appdata/local/temp/tmpgwft3s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11460:7)
>       at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///c:/users/siddhesh/appdata/local/temp/tmpgwft3s/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:11402:5)

Comment: Please include the complete traceback into the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple inputs with `name="email"`.

You need the one in the "Regular Login" section:

```
form = driver.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
username = form.find_element_by_name('email')
username.send_keys('my_email')

password = form.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('my_password')
```

Comment: I think the problem in username.send_keys() line. Because as I said I tried executing it line by line in shell and it gives error at send_keys line.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    password.send_keys('my_email')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 293, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 370, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)