# Selenium takes a long time to find an element.Is there something I can do?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been trying to write a selenium script to login to my [Quora](http://www.quora.com) account.

This is the script I have written.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import getpass
import time

email=raw_input("email: ")
password=getpass.getpass("Password: ")

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.quora.com")

#time.sleep(5)

Form=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form_inputs']")

Form.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(email)

#time.sleep(4)

Form.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(password)

#time.sleep(4)

Form.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Login']").click()
```

The statement 
`Form=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form_inputs']")` takes very long to find the element. In fact, all the find_element statements take very long to do their job.(This could be because of some Javascript snippet to increase the load on selenium, but I could not understand much from the page source)

Is there any way I could do it faster? Similar scripts have worked well for me in Facebook and Google.

EDIT:
Removed the `time.sleep()` calls. It still takes around *6-8 minutes* to find the element.

Comment: what you mean by long time ? You code already wait 5,4,4 seconds before the finding cycle

Comment: Why are you time.sleeping?!

Comment: It takes a long time(like 6-8 minutes) even without the time.sleep call

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it is taking a while is because you are preforming `time.sleep()`

You should not do this, it's bad practice. You should be using WebDriver waits. I would personally go with Implicit waits for your scenario. 
Please see the [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html)

Comment: I have tried without the waits and it still takes a long time(like 6-8 minutes) even without the time.sleep call.

Comment: I am going to suggest there is something wrong with the actual driver implementation then since the code you have posted is not designed to last that long. You would be experiencing NotSuchElementException.
Have you tried using the latest drivers?

Comment: I checked , and it turns out I am using the latest driver. Similar scripts work for me in other sites (like facebook, etc).
Also, interestingly, there is no error, just delay. The element is found by the script, only after a long time.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I've seen here asked on SO multiple times, see:

- [Is Selenium slow, or is my code wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462884/is-selenium-slow-or-is-my-code-wrong)
- [Unable to login to quora using selenium webdriver in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25569426/unable-to-login-to-quora-using-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

I've been able to reproduce the slow code execution using `Firefox`, but the following code works without any delays using `Chrome` or `PhantomJS` driver:

```
import getpass

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

email = raw_input("email: ")
password = getpass.getpass("Password: ")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.quora.com")

form = driver.find_element_by_class_name('regular_login')
form.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(email)
form.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password + Keys.RETURN)
```

---

FYI, for Firefox, it helps to overcome the issue if you fire up `Firefox` with *disabled javascript*:

```
firefox_profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
firefox_profile.set_preference("javascript.enabled", False)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
driver.get('http://www.quora.com/')
```

But, as you would see - you'll quickly get a different set of problems.

Comment: I went through the links and unfortunately( as you would have seen) no one has been able to come up with a working solution on Firefox driver.

The best alternative currently, I guess, is to switch to headless browsers.
I haven't tried with Chrome drivers yet, but the find_element was quite fast with PhantomJS.

Comment: @spiderbat yup, for some reason Firefox is behaving slow (even the latest). I think it is pretty much a good workaround to use `Chrome` or `PhantomJS`.