# Checking if checkbox is selected last full timeout in Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to assert if the checkbox is selected before test select. I've tried it with
`if driver.find_element_by_id('checkbox-id').is_selected():`
and with
`if driver.find_element_by_id('checkbox-id').get_attribute('checked'):`
but both ways it lasts for 10 seconds, which equals my timeout.
When I've tried to do the same with the button: 
`if driver.find_element_by_id('button-id').get_attribute('disabled')`
it's done instantly. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps the button is more nested or farther down/up in the DOM than the checkbox? Maybe there's some flag to search from the top down or vice versa. I found this which could lead somewhere (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28151071/selenium-takes-a-long-time-to-find-an-element-is-there-something-i-can-do).

Comment: I believe it's not nesting in DOM, because it always works fine, never crashed, but every time last full timeout time. If I set timeout for 30 sec, it will wait full 30 sec on every checkbox.